# Constructing a database that collects information from two public surveys and imports answers to a hidden back-end

Tags: database, user-interface, ms-access, database-design, user-controls

I am fairly new to constructing databases and was hoping I could get pointed in the right direction on this project. I have self-taught how to use Microsoft Access (my boss is asking that I specifically use this program) and how to "build a database," but I'm stuck on the abstract, specific functions I'm expected to implement. I'll post what I have come up with from all my research to show I've attempted this on my own before asking, but I would greatly appreciate drawing from the expertise of this community. Thanks for all of your time.

**Context:**

There is a manager survey (1) and an employee survey (2). Every few months, we have leadership roles open up and the managers fill out a survey with all the information regarding the role (opportunity) that they will be in charge of. After all the managers answer, the hopeful employees then review all of the new opportunities, fill out their *own* survey with some similar questions (and others unique), and indicate what opportunity they are most interested in. Once they fill out their surveys, the data is collected and matched up to the opportunity they wrote they wanted.

**My thought process:**

The backend can't be editable by those taking the survey - they (managers and employees) should only be able to add a new, non-existent record to their respective table (from the info entered in their survey). The DB would be stored in a

(1) Manager fills survey out (a form created from Mgr_FormShare - a middle man table), import data to backend db table (Mgr_SurveyDataMain)
    *Split DB
    *Use form as front-end, "properties_data entry: yes"
    *Set up relationship between table inside backend and form

(2) Employee reviews opportunities, chooses DESIRED opportunity# and fills in rest of data (in a form created from Emp_FormShare / middle-man table), import data to backend db table (Emp_SurveyDataMain)
    *Split DB
    *Use form as front-end, "properties_data entry: yes"
    *Set up relationship between table inside backend and form

(3) Run query, imports both surveys into one table in backend (ManagerEmpCombineData)

(4) Append an Assigned field in the Mgr_SurveyDataMain (if an opportunity is discovered as chosen, it's "assigned" status goes from no -> yes)

**My questions:**

Is this the correct way to approach this situation? Is there something I am missing here?

Also, is there a way to ensure all surveys (about 200+ when employee + manager count) will automatically share to the middle-man + only allow one entry per individual? Before splitting, I wanted to make sure that the forms with the properties [DataEntry: "Yes", RecordsSource: "*_FormShare", Each field's *control source*: linked to respective *_FormShare field] would be enough to make sure that they synced. It's okay if I can't ensure only one use, the sync is the most important aspect.

Thanks again for taking the time to go through my question!

Comment: Will the survey that the employees fill out be dependent on the answers that the managers write in the manager survey?

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for responding - the employee survey will not be dependent on the manager's answer. The manager can say "they can expect this," but the employees data is mostly "I would like to get this out of it." The only field that will be identical is the record number that indicates the employee was chosen for which opportunity, so the surveys are completed after being told they have been selected

Comment: Well, the recordnumber will match, but the "assigned" field is also a shared field between manager and employee data. I was hoping that setting a default "yes" to the assigned field in the employee data will update the status in the backend (which is a "no" default after the manager data import).